# Parse SDK : where can I find the version identifier?

Tags: ios, parsing, sdk, version

Where can I find the the version number in the Parse iOS SDK, and/or how can I retrieve it in code?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the PFConstants.h file or just do

```
NSLog(@"%@", PARSE_API_VERSION);
```